# How can I make predictions from a trained model inside a Tensorflow input pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model for emotion recognition, which uses one of VGG's layer's output as an input.

I could manage what I want by running the prediction in a first step, saving the extracted features and then using them as input to my network, but I am looking for a way to do the whole process at once.

The second model uses a concatenated array of feature maps as input (I am working with video data), so I am not able to simply wire it to the output of VGG.

I tried to use a map operation as depicted in the `tf.data.dataset` API documentations this way :

```
def trimmed_vgg16():
  vgg16 = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3))
  trimmed = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg16.get_input_at(0),
                                  outputs=vgg16.layers[-3].get_output_at(0))
  return trimmed

vgg16 = trimmed_vgg16()

def _extract_vgg_features(images, labels):
    pred = vgg16_model.predict(images, batch_size=batch_size, steps=1)
    return pred, labels

dataset = #load the dataset (image, label) as usual
dataset = dataset.map(_extract_vgg_features)
```

But I'm getting this error : `Tensor Tensor("fc1/Relu:0", shape=(?, 4096), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph` which is pretty explicit. I'm stuck here, as I don't see a good way of inserting the trained model in the same graph and getting predictions "on the fly".

Is there a clean way of doing this or something similar ?

Edit: missed a line.
Edit2: added details

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect the layers by first creating the `vgg16` and then retrieving the output of the model as such and afterward you can use that tensor as an input to your own network.

```
vgg16 = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3))

network_input = vgg16.get_input_at(0)
vgg16_out = vgg16.layers[-3].get_output_at(0) # use this tensor as input to your own network
```

Comment: Ah, I think I missed some details. The second model actually takes a sequence of frames as input, so that would not work. For now, I am concatenating the feature maps as part of the input pipeline.  I can maybe find a way of concatenating them as part of the network this way tho, I will look into it

Comment: Then what you can do is give a batched input to the `vgg16` and add a reshape(which flattens the first dimension and works as a concatenation) tensor to the output of the `vgg16` and feed that to your network.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure the batch dimension is sacred and shouldn't be modified. I could add a "batch of batches" first dimension but I think it would require modifying vgg itself.

Comment: I see. I didn't use before but `tf.map_fn` might be useful in this case. So that you don't have to modify `vgg16` itself.